# PhantomJS website requires keypresses for authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, phantomjs

A website I use PhantomJS to log into and scrape a table out of was recently updated and the new version seems to require key presses to actually occur on the username and password fields to login now.

My old code looks like this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
page.open("https://website.location.com/log", function(status) {
    if (status === "success") {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value = "uname";
            document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value = "pass12";
            document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
        });
        window.setTimeout(function() {
           page.render("page.png");
           page.open("https://website.location.com/log/#!/activity/search", function(status) {

                window.setTimeout(function() {
                   page.render("profil.png");
                   console.log(page.content);
                   phantom.exit();
                }, 5000);
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

The old code worked great with the old log in page and console.log output correctly to the script that was calling this phantomjs code, but now I'm not sure where to go from here. I've tried using the page.sendEvent('keypress',page.event.key.U) in several different ways, but any time I insert that bit it seems to freeze up. When I load the page the cursor is automatically in the correct field, but otherwise I figured using tab should switch to the next field and enter would be able to enter my data.

Example of what I've tried

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
page.open("https://website.location.com/log", function(status) {
    if (status === "success") {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.U);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.N);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.A);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.M);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.E);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.Tab);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.P);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.A);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.S);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.S);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.1);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.2);
            document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].click();
        });
        window.setTimeout(function() {
           page.render("page.png");
           page.open("https://website.location.com/log/#!/activity/search", function(status) {

                window.setTimeout(function() {
                   page.render("search.png");
                   console.log(page.content);
                   phantom.exit();
                }, 5000);
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

I've also tried some variations like this that don't seem any better:

```
            page.sendEvent('keypress', "uname");
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.Tab);
            page.sendEvent('keypress', "pass12");
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.Enter);
```

Comment: Are you sure that sending a "tab" event is switching to the other input? It might be sending a "tab" keyboard event to the event handling system instead and bypassing the browser behavior. Maybe try another way to change input focus, perhaps by clicking on the password input.

Comment: Tab even was working correctly actually. Your comment did help lead me down a path of page renders to see what was happening at what stage though so you did help. See the answer I posted if you are curious how I fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem. Key events seemed to be working, but I was typing into the fields before they were loaded. I found this out by doing a series of console writes and page renders to see what the page looked like at certain stages. Tab did work to switch fields and enter worked to submit the fields. I think requiring the keypresses rather than just assigning strings to the values is a symptom of the website now using Angular, but I have no proof to back that up.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
page.open("https://webpage.location.com/log", function(status) {
    if (status === "success") {
        page.render("pretyped.png");
        window.setTimeout(function() {
           page.sendEvent("keypress", "uname");
           page.sendEvent("keypress", page.event.key.Tab);
           page.sendEvent("keypress", "*****");
           page.sendEvent("keypress", page.event.key.Enter);

           page.render("page.png");
           window.setTimeout(function(){
               page.open("https://webpage.location.com/log/api/v1/overview/?endDate=2020-02-05T21:57:13Z&startDate=2020-01-04T21:57:13Z", function(status) {
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                       page.render("profil.png");
                       console.log(page.content);
                       phantom.exit();
                    }, 5000);
                });
           }, 5000);
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```